# How to troubleshoot a VSTO addin that does not load in Microsoft word 365?

Tags: office365, vsto

My VSTO Word Add-in does not display when switched from word 2016 to Microsoft 365 word app. The Add-in was developed using visual studio and the target framework is 4.7.2. I uninstalled the existing Add-in and then re-installed the Add-in. Also Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime and the target .net framework are installed.

The Add-in is loaded and displays fine on my development machine with word 365. But it does not work on a different customer machine. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it does not work on a different customer machine. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

First of all, make sure:

1. All prerequisites were included in the add-in installer.
2. Add-ins can be run, check out the Trust center settings of the host application.
3. No exceptions are thrown at runtime.

As you can see there are various reasons why Office add-ins are not loaded on the end-users machines...

---

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) for more information.

---

Also, I'd recommend use logging mechanisms to detect what is going on on remote machines. Take a look at the [Event logging for Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/event-logging-for-office-solutions?view=vs-2019) page for more information.

Comment: Thank you. The links you provided helped me understand better. If the add-in does not appear in Active or InActive or Disabled Add-ins in Word, does this mean it is not installed at all? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Jyina were you able to fix this issue? I am facing same problem. My VSTO Word plugin is working fine with Microsoft Word, but on "Word 365" I cannot see it loading. Installation on the computer is successful but the plugin does not show up. Any help hints? Thanks.